# Find 8 corners of 3d rectangle using x,y,z vectors and their negatives

Tags: vector, 3d, rectangles

I have 3 vectors. Using these 3 vectors and their negatives, I need to calculate the 8
corners of the 3d rectangle they create.

How can I do that?

Comment: More information.  What are the 3 vectors?  Edges?  Corners?  Measurements?  Is the center of the rectangle on the origin or do we need to calculate a centroid?

Comment: From what I understand the 3 vectors are AXIS. x,y,z.

Comment: They are the axiis?  Like the standard basis <1,0,0>, <0,1,0>, and <0,0,1> (cause that doesn't really tell us anything)?  Or do they represent a rotated basis?  If you want help, you NEED to provide more information.